# Matching Images with openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching

First I'm fairly new to Matching techniques so bear with me:

I am working on an application that matches training images to collected images (samples of single cells).

I've used both SIFT detectors and SURF detectors with FLANN based Matching to match a set of training data to collected Images. But the results I'm getting are really poor. I'm using the same code as in the openCV Documentation:

```
    void foramsMatching(Mat img_object, Mat img_scene){
    int minHessian = 400;

    SiftFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);

    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

    detector.detect(img_object, keypoints_object);
    detector.detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);

    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

    Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

    extractor.compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);
    extractor.compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher

    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
    //BFMatcher matcher;
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);


    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
    printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist)
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
    }

    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
    good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    //-- Localize the object
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;

    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
    {
        //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
        obj.push_back(keypoints_object[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

    //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(img_object.cols, 0);
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(img_object.cols, img_object.rows); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, img_object.rows);
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

    perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

    //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

    //-- Show detected matches
    namedWindow("Good Matches & Object detection", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches);
    //imwrite("../../Samples/Matching.jpg", img_matches);
}
```

Here are the results - 
[image: Matching Two Images]

They are really poor compared to some other results i've seen using these methods. There should be two matches to the two blobs (cells) on the bottom of the screen.

Any Ideas on what I'm doing wrong or how to improve these results?
I was thinking about writing my own Matcher / Discription Extractor since my training images are NOT exact replicas of the cells I am quering.
Is that a good Idea? If so, any tutorials i should look at?

Regards,

Comment: Maybe there's any additional knowledge you can use to eliminate noise? In the picture you've provided, the background and text seems removable quite easily.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are suggesting to try and match only to those spesific regions at the bottom and not to the whold picture? I will try that and report back :) btw how would you go about removing them?

Comment: Absolutely, I think inducing more knowledge about the objects would eliminate false positives. To do that, you can come up e.g. with rules of matched points and areas (size/relation/color etc.)

Comment: how would you go about eliminating noise? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use any knowledge you have. Your objects seem kinda round and have a certain minimum area size. So perform a segmentation and check all segments if they apply to your set of rules (which describe your object). Then only match with the segments that seem of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Converted comment to answer:*

You should apply some kind of pre-processing using available knowledge before you run SIFT/SURF in order to find regions of interest and eliminate noise. Here's the general idea:

1. Perform segmentation
2. Check segments for specific criteria (*) and select interesting candidates.
3. Perform matching on candidate segments.

(*) Things you can use for this step are e.g. area size, shape, color distribution etc. From the example you provided it can e.g. be seen that your objects are round and have a certain minimum size. Use any knowledge you have to eliminate further false positives. You'll need some tuning of course in order to make your set of rules not too restrictive, i.e. keeping true positives.